# cocoon gem error: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

i'm building a relations Company :has_many Notes.

i want to be able to add some new notes to a just created company in the Comany#show resource. so in the company scaffold's show.html.erb

i have follwed step by step the cocoon demostration app and from the github mardown, but the examples shows only the method to add nested attribute into _form.html.erb partial. I don't know if there is some particular things to do differently, but when i try to run the Company#show action it retrieves this error:

**undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass**

this is my code:

show.html.erb:

```
...
  <%= simple_form_for :notes, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |note| %>
    <%= render 'note_fields', :f => note %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Aggiungi Nota', f, :notes, :render_options => {:wrapper => 'inline' } %>
...
```

_note_fields.html.erb:

```
...
<div class="nested-fields">
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= link_to_remove_association "Elimina Nota", f %>
</div>
...
```

Company.rb:

```
  ...
    has_many :notes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
```

Note.rb

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :body, :company_id
     belongs_to :company
end
```

company_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @company = Company.includes(:category, :clients, :notes).find(params[:id])

    @mapCompany = Company.find(params[:id]).to_gmaps4rails

    respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @company }
    end
  end
```

thanks!
Dave

Comment: Can you show your company_controller.rb code for this action?  You are probably not loading up the company resource...

Comment: i have updated the question with the show method in company_controller.rb

Comment: Also, can you provide the stack-trace for the error?

Comment: now i've done a change at my form:

 <%= simple_form_for @company, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |company| %>

this form wrap the simple_fields_for company.notes and now the error is undefined local variable or method `f'

Comment: Throughout your code you've been using `f`, these would now need to change to `company`.  However, `f` would be more correct because `simple_form_for` is yielding a form builder object, not a company.

Comment: sorry i was wrong this is the actual form for the  nested notes and error is the sema above for the form object:
    <%= simple_form_for @company, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |company| %>
      <%= company.simple_fields_for :notes do |note| %>
        <%= render :partial => 'note_fields', :locals => {:f => note} %>
      <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Aggiungi Nota', f, :notes, :render_options => {:wrapper => 'inline' } %>
    <% end %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, the `f` variable was never defined.

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Aggiungi Nota', f, :notes, :render_options => {:wrapper => 'inline' } %>
```

Try using `company` instead of `f`.

Comment: You're missing the 'done' link in your partial, nothing gets saved until you commit it by clicking 'Done':  `<%= f.input :done, :as => :boolean %>`

Comment: is it possible to add a submit button ad call a ajax remote function to create a new note? something like this: <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>

Comment: It's certainly possible, but what attributes are you going to assign to this otherwise-empty note?  Here's an example: `<%= link_to "Create note", company_notes_path(@company), :method => :post, :remote => :true %>`  You may need to use the 'ajax:before' unobtrusive js hook to adjust the attribute details.

Comment: when i'll send the post request for create a note the :body and the :company_id  will be passed and the body can't be blank/empty. I'll work on your example